# Strapi locales API got 502 on reverse proxy domain Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos7, strapi

I’m configuring strapi using Nginx on CentOS7, I’ve successful on config reverse proxy and my domains work. However, when I get in strapi dashboard, my locales API(/i18n/locales) got 502 and it break the application, I’ve tried again with my IP address (IP:port/admin) and this API works normally, any idea with this case?

I inspected the /i18n/locales API, the most diffrent thing is when I use my domain, it connecting to 443 port, and when I tried with my IP address:port, It connect to the 1337 port
(but other APIs still success on 200 with 443 port)

Comment: can you share your nginx configs files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.